# Postgres - How to check for an empty array

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql

I'm using Postgres and I'm trying to write a query like this:

```
select count(*) from table where datasets = ARRAY[]
```

i.e. I want to know how many rows have an empty array for a certain column, but postgres doesn't like that:

```
select count(*) from super_eds where datasets = ARRAY[];
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "]"
LINE 1: select count(*) from super_eds where datasets = ARRAY[];
                                                             ^
```

Comment: ... if datasets=NULL represents ARRAY[], the answers are OK... About about "ARRAY[]", it is a syntax error (!): as depesz answered, an empty array also need datatype, Rory's SQL script need correction, is "ARRAY[]::integer".

Answer (score 116, accepted):

The syntax should be:

```
SELECT
     COUNT(*)
FROM
     table
WHERE
     datasets = '{}'
```

You use quotes plus curly braces to show array literals.

Comment: I'm running PostgreSQL 9.6.9 and while there's no error and no results with '{}', I get the correct results with '[]'. Thanks!

Answer (score 25):

If you find this question in 2020, like I did, the correct answer is

```
select count(*) from table where cardinality(datasets) = 0
```

`cardinality` was added in PostgreSQL 9.4, which is ~2015

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/functions-array.html

Comment: This is the answer. To be clear, `cardinality` "returns the total number of elements in the array, or 0 if the array is empty", which is what you would *expect* of `array_length`, but the later returns NULL when length is zero.

Answer (score 21):

You can use the fact that array_upper and array_lower functions, on empty arrays return null
, so you can:

```
select count(*) from table where array_upper(datasets, 1) is null;
```

Comment: ... ok if datasets=NULL represents ARRAY[], but and about "ARRAY[]", it is a syntax error (!). How to create a empty array??

Comment: it's error only because it can't tell what datatype it's array off. add cast: select ARRAY[]::int4[];

Comment: Thank you, I don't understand why the top answer doesn't work for me. But your answer worked perfectly.

Answer (score 5):

```
Solution Query:
```

```
select id, name, employee_id from table where array_column = ARRAY[NULL]::array_datatype;
```

```
Example:
```

table_emp:

```
id (int)| name (character varying) | (employee_id) (uuid[])
1       | john doe                 | {4f1fabcd-aaaa-bbbb-cccc-f701cebfabcd, 2345a3e3-xxxx-yyyy-zzzz-f69d6e2edddd }
2       | jane doe                 | {NULL}


select id, name, employee_id from tab_emp where employee_id = ARRAY[NULL]::uuid[];

    -------
2       | jane doe                 | {NULL}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT  COUNT(*)
FROM    table
WHERE   datasets = ARRAY(SELECT 1 WHERE FALSE)
```